# Java: JSONObject.toString() - adding extra space after colon (":" -> ": ")

Tags: java, json, tostring

Been googling a while but haven't found anything useful since keywords are too common.

Currently in my Java code method `toString()` (called on some `JSONObject` object) produces output like this:

```
{"key_name":<numerical_value>}
```

while what I need (due to the fact that parser on the other side of the project is imperfect) is:

```
{"key_name": <numerical_value>}
```

The only difference is that extra space after colon. Is there any `JSONObject` builtin way to do it or do I need some handwritten simple string operation for it?

Comment: hi you can use the ObjectMapper class to solve the problem. toString() is not right way to solve the problem.

Comment: why? what I need is exactly a string. it's just a matter of parsing it by the other, remote app. my app produces the JSONObject and transfers it as a json formatted string - that's the protocol some other parties proposed and agreed on.

Comment: While this may work, the real solution is of course to fix the parser on the other side.

Comment: your JSONObject is taking the extra space, then remove the extra space if you feel that is the only problem. i feel you should use the ObjectMapper to  convert the java object to json, no need to make the JSONObject again.

Comment: @Henry - absolutly right about this and this was our first solution which also is the only proper one. sadly, it's not achievable at the current moment so we have to find a way to workaround this.

Comment: can you use the JSONObject<String,Integer> obj=new JSONObject<String,Integer>(); when creating the object

Comment: One way is to write your own JSON serializer or maybe patch the current implementation (within a new package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only imagine building a custom `JSONStringer`. In fact, it could be a `JSONWriter` built using a `StringWriter`. Then you override all the `value` methods to add a space before calling parent class method.

```
class JSONSpaceStringer extends JSONWriter {
    private StringWriter sw;

    JSONSpaceStringer(StringWriter sw) {
        parent(sw); // initialize parent
        this.sw = sw;
    }

    @Override
    public JSONWriter value(long l) throws JSONException {
        sw.write(" "); // add an initial space
        parent.value(l); // and let parent class do the job...
    }

// same for all other value methods
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below code. it will help you to solve the problem.

```
 package com.javamad.utils;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

    public class JsonUtils {

        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JsonUtils.class.getName());


        public static <T> T jsonToJavaObject(String jsonRequest, Class<T> valueType)
                throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE,false);     
            T finalJavaRequest = objectMapper.readValue(jsonRequest, valueType);
            return finalJavaRequest;

        }

        public static String javaToJson(Object o) {
            String jsonString = null;
            try {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE,true);  
                jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(o);

            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
            return jsonString;
        }

    }
```

Comment: far from being an answear to my question. what I need is a pretty solution using JSONObject - if there is a pretty one. still looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

just extend MinimalPrettyPrinter

```
public class TestObjectMapper2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Person person = mapper.readValue("{\"name\":\"frank\",\"age\":20,\"inq\":[\"2\",\"35\"]}",Person.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writer(new MinimalPrettyPrinter(){
            @Override
            public void writeObjectEntrySeparator(JsonGenerator jg)
                throws IOException
            {
                jg.writeRaw(',');
                jg.writeRaw(' ');
            }

            @Override
            public void writeArrayValueSeparator(JsonGenerator jg)
            throws IOException
            {
                jg.writeRaw(',');
                jg.writeRaw(' ');
            }
        }).writeValueAsString(person));
    }

    private static class Person{
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", age=" + age +
                '}';
            }

            private String name;
            private Integer age;

            private List<String> inq;

            public List<String> getInq()
            {
                return inq;
            }

            public void setInq(List<String> inq)
            {
                this.inq = inq;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public Integer getAge() {
                return age;
            }

            public void setAge(Integer age) {
                this.age = age;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
output: {"name":"frank", "age":20, "inq":["2", "35"]}
```